# Insert an html line break in a div after colon character with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, string, replace

I have this div, a title in a jqplot chart:

```
<div class="jqplot-title" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 465px; text-align: center;">Total: $0.46</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to stick a `<br>` tag after the "Total:", to make it 2 lines.

I've searched around, but most of the string replacements I've found are overkill for this; I'm hoping there's a succinct solution.

Comment: Is there a `.jqplot-title` that doesn't contain the text `Total:`? If so use a more narrow solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20842057/144665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should be able to handle this.  Something like:

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).html(
        $(this).html().replace(':', ':<br />')
    );
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ds6vC/).

Comment: All these approaches work great, I just accepted this since it's the shortest one.

Comment: -1 This would replace all matches of `$('div')`'s html with the first matching occurrence of `$('div')`'s html. The second selector `div` is way too broad here.

Comment: @iambriansreed: Good catch, I didn't notice that.  I've updated the code with a modified approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to get the inner text of the element using jquery, then do a simple javascript `replace()` on the string to swap the space for a `<br />`.

`var textToReplace = $("jqplot-title").innerHtml();`

`$("jqplot-title").innerHtml(textToReplace.replace(" ","<br />");`

Answer (score 1):

This ensures you are only adding a `<br>` tag after `Total:`.

```
$('.jqplot-title').html(function(index, html){
    return html.replace('Total:','Total:<br>');
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml